# How to integrate custom allure plugin with jenkins allure plugin

Tags: jenkins, allure, jenkins-cli

We have created My tab plugin which we can use from allure-commandline but same we need to use in our Jenkins CI.
In our Jenkins CI machine allure command line is not installed and in the same machine, we are using allure as a Jenkins plugin.

Can anyone please help me to integrate my custom allure plugin with Jenkins allure plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You can re-pack Allure Commandline with your plugin pre-installed and then use this package in Allure Commandline configuration in "Global Tool Configuration" in Jenkins

[image]